# Regex substitute multiple lines for a single line

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a plain text file in which I need to substitute multiple consecutive lines of text with a single replacement line.  For example, when I have a date and time, followed by a blank line, followed by a page number,

```
11/13/2018 08:33:00

Page 1 of 1
```

I'd like to replace it with a single line (e.g., `PAGE BREAK`).

I've tried

```
sed 's/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\n\nPage \d of \d/PAGE BREAK/g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

and

```
perl -pe 's/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\n\nPage \d of \d/PAGE BREAK/g' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

but it leaves the text unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sed and Perl process the input line by line. You can tell Perl to load the whole file into memory by using `-0777` (if it's not too large):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\n\nPage [0-9]+ of [0-9]+=PAGE BREAK=g'
```

Note that I used `[0-9]`, because `\d` can match ٤, ໖, ६, or .

I also used `s===` instead of `s///` so I don't have to backslash the slashes in the date part.

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl variant

```
$ cat page_break.txt
123 45 jh kljl
11/13/2018 08:33:00

Page 1 of 1
ghjgjh hkjhj
fhfghfghfh
11/13/2018 08:33:00

Page 1 of 2
ghgigkjkj

$ perl -ne '{ if ( (/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/ and $x++)or ( /^\s*$/ and $x++) or (/Page \d of \d/ and $x++) ){} if($x==0) { print "$_" } if($x==3) { print "PAGE BREAK\n"; $x=0} }' page_break.txt
123 45 jh kljl
PAGE BREAK
ghjgjh hkjhj
fhfghfghfh
PAGE BREAK
ghgigkjkj

$
```